# Proper tree NoSQL structure with focus on full-text searching

Tags: mongodb, database-design, tree, database, nosql

I developing an app with tree(folder-file) structure, on which I should perform full-text searches with MongoDB. I did a research on the best tree structure practices and found [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/) great article, but I still can not decide which DB structure will fit my needs.

I have the following requirements in my mind:

- I should be able to perform full-text search on individual folders, as well as everything from specific users
- The folders/files should be shareable, so I need to be able to perform full-text search on all items accessible by specific user

I've been thinking about the following structures.

**Structure 1**

```
Fields of Users collection

 1. _id - objectid
 2. name - string

Fields of Folders collection

 1. _id - objectid
 2. name - string
 3. owner - objectid
 4. sharedWith - array of objectIds
 5. location - objectid of parent folder, null if in root
 6. createDate - datetime

Fields of File collection

 1. _id - objectid
 2. name - string
 3. owner - objectid
 4. sharedWith - array of objectIds
 5. data - string
 6. location - objectId of folder
 7. createDate - datetime
```

So here comes my questions:

1. Should I use model tree structures with Parent References or Child References?
2. Should I use 1 collection for both files and folders(with type field) or I should separate them.
3. Does it worth to have only folder collection and nest documents in it.

This were my most important questions, thought I will greatly appreciate any advice on how I can improve the structure. I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask such questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how far you want/need the setup to scale. For small numbers of files, folders, and files per folder it doesn't matter too much. That said,

1. I'd use references from children to parents. Parents (folders) may have hundreds or thousands of children (files and folders). This might be ok to store as references in one folder document, but most likely in that case you would want to index the array to support fast queries like "is file x in folder y?", and the array would be frequently changing. A large, frequently changing, indexed array is a recipe for bad performance in MongoDB. If you have only a couple hundred or so children per folder, you might be able to get away with storing references to all children in the parent, as long as you don't rely on that array being indexed for your queries. This essentially means you'd put a reference from the children to the parents to support the same queries.
2. I'd use one collection since you want to return both in response to many queries. Add a field to identify folders, like `folder : true or something.
3. No, it won't work to have folder documents with many nested layers. MongoDB in general doesn't support recursive or arbitrary-depth operations, making it difficult to work with such structures.